# Why doesnt js server receive HTTP post request?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, http

I am writing an android app that sends a .wav file over http to a nodeJs server running on a pc. The node Js server simply prints a message to the screen when it receives a POST request. It also prints the contents of the file received. On the Android side, a POST request containing the file is made to the server when a button is clicked. The problem is that when the button is clicked, the server never receives anything. I have tried making the POST request using the POSTman software and it works fine.

android code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("MY TAG: ", "SENDING....");
                send();
                Log.d("MY TAG: ", "SENT.");
            }
        });

    }

    void send(){

        String url = "http://"my ip goes here":4000/extract_indicators/audio/3";
        File exStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(exStore.getAbsolutePath() + "/AudioRecord/recording0.wav");
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
                    new FileInputStream(file), -1);
            reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
            reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            //Do something with response...
            Log.d("HTTP ", "RESPONSE: " + response);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            // show error
        }
    }
}
```

NodeJs code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
const fs = require('fs');
const wav = require('wav');
let upload = multer();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'audio/wav', limit: '50mb' }));

app.post('/extract_indicators/audio/:user_id', upload.any(), function(req, res) {
    console.log("RECIEVED AUDIO TO EXTRACT INDICATORS: ", req.body);
    let formData = req.body;
    let files = req.files;
    //fs.writeFileSync('audiotest.wav', req.files[1].buffer);
    console.log('form data', formData, 'file' , files);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(4000);
```

Logcat when button is pressed:

```
D/ViewRootImpl@ad416c[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@ad416c[MainActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
D/MY TAG:: SENDING....
D/MY TAG:: SENT.
```

**edit:**

This is the editted code following the first answer to the original question. I am still having the same problem however.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Log.d("MY TAG: ", "SENDING....");
                new wavSender().execute();
                Log.d("MY TAG: ", "SENT.");
            }
        });

    }

    private class wavSender extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


        public wavSender() {
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            String url = "http://my ip goes here:4000/extract_indicators/audio/3";
            File exStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File(exStore.getAbsolutePath() + "/AudioRecord/recording0.wav");
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

                InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
                        new FileInputStream(file), -1);
                reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
                reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
                httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                //Do something with response...
                Log.d("HTTP ", "RESPONSE: " + response);

            } catch(Exception e) {
                // show error
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String temp) {
            Log.d("MY TAG", "POST EXECUTE HAS RAN");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably executing a network function inside the mainthread, it should probably throw an error but you suppressed it using `try-catch`. You can use `AsyncTask` to perform network calls, please refer to this link on how to use it: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: I am now doing this through an Async task however I am getting the same behavior without any errors thrown in the logcat or debugger.

Comment: Log the exception. It contains useful info rather than doing nothing there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, turns out the http client was throwing an access denied exception. However the AsyncTask at least performs the network call correctly.